# How does the V-280 Valor maintains its Center of Gravity (CG) when it is converted from helicopter (hover) mode to plane (flight) mode?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-physics, cg, tiltrotor

[image: V-280 in hover mode]
[image: V-280 in transition mode]
[image: V-280 in flight mode]

[Picture source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RnbU-NrtXyA):

The above pictures are showing three modes of V-280 Valor: ***hover or VTOL/hover mode***, ***transition mode*** from VTOL to flight, and ***flight/air plane mode***. As we may see, there is a CG shifting in that conversion, its CG must be shifted backward to compensate the weight of the two rotors and their supporting cases. I guessed its CG is exactly at the rotors' interconnecting shaft. But when the rotors are tilted forward, the CG must be shifted backward as the load-factor of the rotors/propellers are changed significantly. Indeed, during the tilting forward, the front side load maybe supported by the thrust generated by the rotors/propellers. But after they are inline to the fuselage, no more thrust can compensate. As we know, the tilt rotor of V-280 Valor is different than tilt rotor of V-22 Osprey, which with the V-22, the engines themselves also involved, they are tilted backward-up so the CG remains in its location.

My question then, how does the V-280 Valor maintains its Center of Gravity (CG) when it is converted from helicopter (hover) mode to plane (flight) mode?

Comment: On most aircraft, as fuel is burned, the position of the CG changes, albeit slowly, and the pilots or autopilot compensate for that.  Given that the transition between hover and forward flight is not instantaneous, why do you believe that the CG has to "be maintained", rather than it shifts and that shift is compensated for with the flight controls?

Comment: @RalphJ, in most aircraft, the fuel tank is located on the CG. Indeed, it is changed time after time, but the changes is very slowly. And the fuel flow is designed such that way so will now flow so fast when the aircraft being banking such as when making turn. Control the fuel flow is the way to handle it. So, what is the way to handle its CG shifting during the transition in this V-280 which it is changed quite rapidly compared to that fuel changes?

Answer (score 2):

First an foremost, the CG **does** shift, I strongly believe that there is not counter-action to this. Furthermore I speculate that this is a clever design feature in order to satisfy two needs in flight (however I cannot proof this...)

1. In Hover flight, the CG is exactly under the rotor shaft, therefore no cyclic trim input is needed which reduces the stress on the shaft and also on the actuators as the aircraft can hover without the need for constant cyclic input.
2. In forward flight, the CG shifts forward, as you already noticed in your question. This has the added benefit that the forward CG adds more longitudinal stability in forward flight. Infact this is needed, as the V-280 would otherwise be unstable in forward flight, which would vastly complicate the flight control system.

This CG-shift is probably already the case for the V-22, it is just not that obvious as the entire nacelles rotate.

Unfortunately I could not find a good reference quickly, but you might be interested in this [dissertation](https://etda.libraries.psu.edu/files/final_submissions/20780), on page 55 the trim values for a V-22 like aircraft is given.

Comment: Quote: "Furthermore I speculate that *this is a clever design* feature in order to satisfy two needs in flight." Yes, indeed, a very clever designed, of course.

Comment: "In Hover flight, the CG is exactly under the rotor shaft, therefore *no cyclic trim input is needed which reduces the stress on the shaft and also on the actuators* as the aircraft can hover without the need for constant cyclic input." Of course it should not use cyclic to overcome the CG shifting. It will waste power a lot.

Comment: "*In forward flight, the CG shifts forward*, as you already noticed in your question. This has the *added benefit that the forward CG adds more longitudinal stability in forward flight.*" That is part of my question and it is why I ask this question as every plane has slight pitch down  as it is required to maintain the airplane glide in case total power failure.

Comment: @AirCraftLover: in helicopter mode the CG must not be **exactly** under the rotors (which is impossible) rather it must be within a well defined forward and backward limit, limit that normally depends on the weight.

Comment: @AirCraftLover given that the V280 features a fully digital flight control system, the V280 will most definitly crash given a total power failure. Loss of power would mean no more control, as the chain from pilot input to actuators would be cut. In that case the aircraft would enter some sort of dive/spin/uncontrollable attitude or all of these options, therefore inevitably crashing

Comment: Perhaps I should clarify, I mean in the event of total *electric* power failure

Answer (score 1):

> how does the V-280 Valor maintains its Center of Gravity (CG) when it is converted from helicopter (hover) mode to plane (flight) mode?

It doesn't. And there's no need for the CG to be maintained fixed among helicopter and aeroplane configuration.

1. In helicopter configuration, CG should be as much as possible centered between and under the two rotors in order to minimise stress on the rotor shafts and this limitation is for sure valid also for the V-22 and the V-280. The limits within which the CG must lie is called *CG envelope* and depends mainly on the weight, being the envelope smaller at higher weight. For example for the R44 it looks something like that ([source](https://bst-tsb.gc.ca/eng/rapports-reports/aviation/2009/A09P0210/A09P0210.html); on x-axis distance from the nose; on y-axis weight):

[image: R44 CG envelope]

2. In transition phase the two rotors have to be rotated forward just of a very small angle to gain forward speed, with a relevantly small forward shift of CG as well. Just as an example, main rotors of conventional helicopters are tilted forward of some 3 to 5° and that's enough to make them reach forward speeds as high as 300kmh (200mph). This small forward CG shift has anyway a smaller impact than if it was toward the back, as can be seen from the previous plot.
3. Finally, in aeroplane configuration CG shifts are less of a problem than in helicopter configuration since CG shifts are compensated by the horizontal stabiliser, just like any conventional aeroplane. And just like any conventional aeroplane, CG must lie within the limits of the longitudinal stability, as well explained for example in [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/47306/does-static-longitudinal-stability-require-download-on-the-tail).

---

By the way, since combustion engines are quite heavy (as much as some 10% of the empty weight) and since in the V-22 they rotate too during transition phase, I would actually expect a bigger CG shift in the V-22 compared to the V-280, where only the two relatively light rotors rotate.

Comment: Quote: "Anyway in aeroplane configuration *CG shifts are less of a problem than in helicopter configuration since CG shifts are compensated by the horizontal stabiliser*, as long as the limits of the longitudinal stability are respected." Yes, indeed, but **still need to be compensated**. Every changes must be compensated. But my question, how does it compensated/maintained? I am asking the way it does.

Comment: How longitudinal stability works is another lengthy topic, you can find a good answer about it [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/47306/does-static-longitudinal-stability-require-download-on-the-tail). I linked that answer also in my text.

Answer (score 1):

The center of gravity does not need to be exactly under the rotor shaft in helicopters or tiltrotors. This would be difficult to manage, and to mitigate the problems involving non aligned CoG and lift, helicopters and V-22 Osprey, as well as most likely the V-280 Valor use [swash plates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swashplate_%28aeronautics%29#Animations) that transfer the center of lift of the rotor disk(s) as per commands from the pilot or flight computer.

During transition, before the forward speed is sufficient to create balancing force from the tail assembly, as the rotor is tilted forward the balance of CoL vs CoG is maintained by shifting the CoL as necessary via the swash plate.

Also note that during transition the lift must be increased in the beginning stages if level flight is to be maintained. As the rotor tilts forward, the vertical component of the lift decreases, and it must be increased before forward speed is sufficient for the main wing to produce lift. This is also done by the swash plate by incresing AoA of the blades.

There is speculation in the web about V-280 not using a swash plate, but instead conteolling the AoA of each blade individually by electric motors, but I was unable to find any authorative source for this.

Comment: "The center of gravity does not need to be exactly under the rotor shaft in helicopters or tiltrotors. This would be difficult to manage, and to mitigate the problems involving non aligned CoG and lift, helicopters and V-22 Osprey, as well as most likely the V-280 Valor use swash plates that transfer the center of lift of the rotor disk(s) as per commands from the pilot or flight computer." If the CoG is not below the interconnecting shaft, then the cyclic must be applied, and it will reduce lifting force several percent. But however, it is part of my question. Is it the case?

Comment: "During transition, before the forward speed is sufficient to create balancing force from the tail assembly, as the rotor is tilted forward the balance of CoL vs CoG is maintained by shifting the CoL as necessary via the swash plate." For short period of time, it is possible to apply cyclic to the aircraft, but not for long time as the efficiency will be reduced significantly depend of the AoA is applied. If it is negative, the power reduction will be > 25%. But then, what about during the flight?

Comment: In normal  airplane, CoG is maintained by the horizontal stabilizer. But in this V-280, is that technique also applied? Indeed, as the V-280 also an airplane, the airplane must be slightly tilted down to make it glide able if the case all power failure. But however, it is just my opinion, I am asking the firm answer.

Comment: Yes, cyclic must be used during hover and transition, as I described in my answer, to maintain balance. During flight in airplane mode, it is not needed.

Comment: Why wouldn't the V-280be able to tilt downwards to glide? Of course it can. During airplane mode it is contolled as any other airplane is.

Comment: @Jpe61 i am not sure how well the v280 or any other of these convertiplanes glide... That is actually a really interesting question imo

Comment: My guess is they glide better than the space shuttle, which in turn glides better than a brick 